# Parallel implementation of least angle regression

Tags: r

I'm looking for the R package or script which the least angle regression or lasso implemented in parallel fashion.
Does anyone knows some?

Comment: Do you want to run a single (presumably huge) regression on several cores or machines, or do you want to run several regressions in parallel? The latter is easily achieved, e.g., with the `parallel` package.

Comment: Both of them is the objective of my work. but how can I implement  M <- lars(x,y,type="lasso",normalize=TRUE,intercept=TRUE,use.Gram=TRUE) in parallel ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The **Lars** package in R will do this. Check out this package - http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lars/index.html

And the R command would be

```
lars(x, y, type = c("lasso"))
```

Comment: Yes, but it's not parallel implementation of it. if you run it on the server, it will use just one of the cores.